# refresh and retrieve source code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

To help me explain what I want to achieve I will first show an image:

[image]

On the right hand side I have a `<div>` and inside it, jquery along with ajax is injecting an html page with css.

I have 2 problems.

1. when I change text inside that div, so for example I edited `This text can be edited by the user` to `hello`, the  source code of that page is not updated, maybe it is due to the fact that it is injected. What can I do to solve this? maybe somehow dynamically refresh the page upon interaction from the user? Please give me an example.
2. Second problem will only appear once first one is solved, and that is, how do I retrieve that "updated" source code and update/save that file so changes will apply when page is reloaded?

In my database I have a file location i.e. example.html and I am taking that and injecting it onto the page but I do not know if it's possible to update that file or rather have source code in that table which is injected onto the page and upon changes, update source code rather than update file.

Comment: You're looking at the wrong source code, hit F12, a live source can be found there.

Comment: that is true, this solves problem one. how about second problem to retrieve and save that source code or rather update it

Comment: @Joel Hinz I think laravel tag is required here as I do use laravel to do this website i.e. working with templates etc and sometimes it is relative

Comment: You would need to do that on the client side since the server side can not run your AJAX.  So after your AJAX runs, you can use `document.documentElement.outerHTML` to grab the source and you'd probably need AJAX to send that back to the server.

Comment: @user3158900 can you please give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are trying to achieve, but heres a quick example where you can utilize Vue to directly insert html into the div if thats what you want

Note use {{{ input }}} to unescape the html

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    input: '# <div>This can be edited by the user</div>'
  }
});
```

```css
.box{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #cecece;
}

input{
   width: 100%;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <textarea>Comment stuff</textarea>
  <button>Button</button>
  <br>
  <input v-model="input">
  
  <div class="box">
    {{input}}
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Something like this I assume, but 1 question how can I refresh a div when for example text is added into it without reloading the page so that it stays there. So for example when I run the page it shows "This can be edited by the user" and that's what source code shows, so when i used                 var code = document.getElementById('content-link2').innerHTML;
console.log(code); that code is there. However if I change that text, var code doesn't update so it still says "This..." So I need a way to refresh a div without reloading page